# Building Android APK with Proguard and getting a Class not found Exception

Tags: android, proguard

I have been trying to create an Android APK with proguard. The application works when installed, but the minute it attempts to use an object from com.google.android.gms.common.images.ImageManager, it throws the following exception. Im trying to use this class for use with Google Play Game Services.

```
07-23 01:01:32.382: E/Parcel(615): Class not found when     unmarshalling:com.google.android.gms.common.images.ImageManager$b, e: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.common.images.ImageManager$b
07-23 01:01:32.387: E/AndroidRuntime(615): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-23 01:01:32.387: E/AndroidRuntime(615): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.google.android.gms.common.images.ImageBroadcastReceiver: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: com.google.android.gms.common.images.ImageManager$b
07-23 01:01:32.387: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2287)
07-23 01:01:32.387: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:140)
07-23 01:01:32.387: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1313)
07-23 01:01:32.387: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-23 01:01:32.387: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-23 01:01:32.387: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4938)
07-23 01:01:32.387: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-23 01:01:32.387: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-23 01:01:32.387: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
07-23 01:01:32.387: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
07-23 01:01:32.387: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-23 01:01:32.387: E/AndroidRuntime(615): Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: com.google.android.gms.common.images.ImageManager$b
07-23 01:01:32.387: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2077)
07-23 01:01:32.387: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1965)
07-23 01:01:32.387: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2226)
07-23 01:01:32.387: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223)
07-23 01:01:32.387: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:1165)
07-23 01:01:32.387: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.content.Intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.java:4489)
07-23 01:01:32.387: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at com.google.android.gms.common.images.ImageBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(SourceFile:21)
07-23 01:01:32.387: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2280)
07-23 01:01:32.387: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  ... 10 more
```

Inside my proguard-project.txt I have the following, but it still isnt good enough:

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.common.images.** { *; }
#Google Play service
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}
```

Here is the project.properties file just in case:

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems. 
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.
#
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available 

properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}\\tools\\proguard\\proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

# Project target.
target=android-17
android.library.reference.1=../android-sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib
```

Comment: It appeared to be an issue with the jar file for Google Play Game Services. I grabbed a jar from revision 8 and proguard worked. Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this ?

https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting

> Proguard issues
>
> If you are using Proguard and are seeing errors on the obfuscated APK,
>   check the target API level on your AndroidManifest.xml. Make sure to
>   set it to 17 or above.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I Changed android:targetSdkVersion="17" to be 17 but still having issue with Image Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Add `-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**` in your proguard file.